# Lightning component navigatetoURL to open Lightning App Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, url, onclick

Using Aura:component with figure onclick to open URL which is another Lightning App Page. Cannot get the URL syntax correct. It's a managed package so will have different MyDomains. The Lightning App Page is just "ProviderOne1". Tried without namespace, with, without "n/" etc.

**Controller**

```
({
handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({
                "url": "n/hdone__ProviderOne1"
    }).fire();
}
```

})

Comment: last i checked you shouldn't be using navigatetourl unless you are in communities or navigating to an external site.

Comment: Lightning App Page is your page created by lightning app builder or any custom component?

Comment: Its created by Lightning App Builder. If I was navigating to an Object Page, Record Page, etc. then I'd be using navigateTo(whatever). But they dont have that for Lightning App Pages.